# Need clarify the use of word "locates" in the sentence

Tags: meaning, word-usage, sentence, verb-forms

My English teacher asked a quiz question:

> ***The dancing club*** *_*__ ***north of this district***
>
> a. lays
>
> b. lies
>
> c. locates
>
> d. lain

The answer was given as **c. locates**. I feel something is wrong with this answer, because I usually read sentences like *"[Something] **is located** in/at [somewhere]"*, so I think ***locate*** should be used in passive form. In my opinion, ***lies*** may be able to be put here, or ***lays*** if  ***in*** were added.

Please clarify what the correct answer is.

Comment: Get another teacher.

Comment: Also, it’s *“dance club”*, not *“*dancing club”*, which further supports @RegDwightАΑA’s position on the matter.

Comment: I suppose it's *possible* that the teacher has made a simple mistake and written "C" instead of "B" (or mixed up the order of the answers since preparing the questions). But that shouldn't happen.

Comment: There are so many problems with your teacher's question that I'd even bet the club in question is actually _south_ of the district.

Comment: The teacher spoke the answer by word, not by B and C. Actually, my friend had asked me this question before (homework), and today she got the answer. I was also surprised that my answer (`lies`) was wrong. I will have her have him clarify next time they meet. I can't believe no one in that class asked him to explain.

Comment: _Lies_ is **not** wrong; _lies_ is correct. The others are all incorrect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your instructor believes that *locates* is the correct answer, they are mistaken. You have to say either ***is*** located or *lies*, with the first perhaps the more commonly heard.

The other possibilities you list are wrong: *lays* is the wrong verb altogether, and *lain* is a past participle without any auxiliary. And as you observe, *locates* makes no sense by itself.